# Jest Unit Test to see if Function is defined with specific argument

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

Brand new to JS and Unit Testing. Trying to test if `getPrices()` has the argument `taxBoolean` defined. So all I'm trying to test is that the following would be true:

```
function getPrices(){ //add code here };
```

Here is what I have tried based off an example I found.
**The funcitons**

```
function getPrices() {

}


// Implement getDiscount()
function getDiscount() {
    
}

// Call getDiscount()

module.exports = {getPrices, getDiscount};
```

**The Unit Tests**

```
const {getPrices, getDiscount} = require(`./finalProject`);

test('returns true if getPrices exists', () => {
    expect(getPrices).toBeDefined();
})

test('returns true if getDiscount exists', () => {
    expect(getDiscount).toBeDefined();
})

test('test console log inside getPrices', () => {
    expect(getPrices(taxBoolean)).toBe(true)
})
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You're super close. Just make the last test match the first test but add the param like this and that should work.

```
test('test console log inside getPrices', () => {
    expect(getPrices(taxBoolean)).toBeDefined();
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but my test is still failing.